# MIPS - Having trouble with subroutines

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine

I'm working on a lab in class and I completely understand the concepts here, but I'm thinking I made a small error somewhere, most likely in the second subroutine. I'm having a hard time debugging this and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Also, to be clear, it compiles and accepts inputs correctly, it has something to do with my calculation. It outputs the wrong amount of total cost.
 Thanks!

> **Directions & Sample Output:**
>
> Write a program for a grocery store to calculate the total charge for customers.
>
> In the main:
>
> > Your program should ask customer the number of items that he/she is purchasing and it should check to see it is less than or equal to `20` items , then your program should pass than number to `FillPriceArray` subroutine and call `FillPriceArray` subroutine.
> >
> > `FillPriceArray` subroutine fills the array, accumulate the prices and return the sum to `main`.
> >
> > In the `main` you get the number of coupons form user (it should be the same as the number of items) and pass the coupon number to `FillCouponArray` sub and call `FillCouponArray` to fill the `CouponArray`.
> >
> > `FillCouponArray` sub gets the coupon amount. The coupon should be less than item price and coupon should not be more than `$10` if the coupon is more than item price or exceed `$10` then you place `0` in the `CouponArray` for that coupon. Also the `FillCouponArray` sub accumulates the coupons and return it to `main`.
> >
> > Finally your `main` program should calculate the total charge by subtracting the total price from total discount coupons and out put the total charge with a thank you message on the screen.
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Please enter the number of item you are purchasing(should be less than or equal to 20) 
> 21
> Sorry too many items to purchase!! Please enter number of items you are purchasing
> 3
>
> Please enter the price of item 1    
> 10
> Please enter the price of item 2    
> 10
> Please enter the price of item 3    
> 20
>
> Please enter the number of coupons that you want to use.
> 4       
> Too many Coupons!! Please enter the number of coupons that you want to use.
> 3
>
> Please enter the amount of coupon 1
> 15
> This coupon is not acceptable
> Please enter the amount of coupon 2
> $5
>
> Please enter the amount of coupon 3
> $5
> Your total charge is:     $30
>
> Thank you for shopping with us.
> ```

My code so far:

```
    .data
str:    .asciiz "\n Please enter the number of items you are purchasing (should be less than or equal to 20): "
str1:   .asciiz "\n Sorry too many items to purchase! Please enter number of items you are purchasing"
str2:   .asciiz "\n Please enter the price of item "
str3:   .asciiz "\n Please enter the number of coupons that you want to use. "
str4:   .asciiz "\n Too many coupons! Please enter the number of coupons that you want to use."
str5:   .asciiz "\n Please enter the amount of coupon "
str6:   .asciiz "\n This coupon is not acceptable"
str7:   .asciiz "\n Your total charge is: $"
str8:   .asciiz "\n Thank you for shopping with us."
str9:   .asciiz ":\t"
priArr: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
couArr: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    .text

main:       li $t1, 20          #input can't be greater than 20 items
            li $t2, 1           #item counter (starting at 1)
            li $t3, 0           #loop counter
            li $t5, 10          #laods 10 into t5
            la $s0, priArr          #loads address of Price Array to $s0
            la $s1, couArr          #loads address of Coupon Array to $s1

            li $v0, 4           #asks for input
            la $a0, str
            syscall

            li $v0, 5           #load integer
            syscall

            add $s3, $0, $v0        #adds input to $s3

            bgt $s3, $t1, error1        #if $s3 > $t1 --> error1

            add $a1, $s3, $0        #adds input to $a1 (limit)

            jal FillPriceArray      #jumps to subroutine to fill array with prices

            add $s2, $0, $v1        #adds price sum to s2

            #################################################################################

            la $s0, priArr          #points pointer to first location of arr1

            li $v0, 4           #asks for how many coupons
            la $a0, str3
            syscall

            li $v0, 5           #loads integer into $v0
            syscall

            bgt $v0, $s3, error2        #if input > limit, go to error

            add $t4, $v0, 0         #adds input to t4

            add $a3, $t4, $0        #adds input to a3

            jal FillCouponArray     #jumps to subroutine to fill array with coupon

            add $s5, $v1, $0        #adds coupon input to s5

            sub $t7, $s2, $s5       #subtracts price sum and coupons and puts it into t7

            li $v0, 4           #prints output
            la $a0, str7
            syscall

            li $v0, 1           #prints dollar amount
            add $a0, $t7, $0
            syscall


exit:       li $v0, 10
            syscall

FillPriceArray:li $t0, 10           #adds limit($a1) to $t0
               li $t1, 1            #adds counter to $t1
               li $t2, 0            #adds loop counter to $t2
               add $t3, $a1, $0     #adds input to t3


        read:   beq $t3, $t2, end       #if $a1 (counter) = $t2 , return to the previous address in main

            li $v0, 4           #asks for price of item
            la $a0, str2
            syscall

            li $v0, 1           #prints counter
            add $a0, $t1, $0
            syscall

            li $v0, 4           #prints colon and tab
            la $a0, str9
            syscall

            li $v0, 5           #loads integer into $v0
            syscall

            sw $v0, 0($s0)          #stores the integer into array1

            add $t1, $t1, 1         #adds 1 to counter
            add $t2, $t2, 1         #adds 1 to loop counter
            add $s0, $s0, 4         #increments array
            add $t4, $t4, $v0       #adds number to sum

            j read

        end:add $v1, $t4, $0
            jr $ra


FillCouponArray:    li $t0, 10          #adds 10 into t0
                    li $t1, 1           #adds counter to $t1
                    li $t2, 0           #adds loop counter to $t2
                    add $t4, $a3, $0        #adds coupon input to t4

        read1:  beq $t4, $t2, end1      #beg of loop

            lw $v0, 0($s0)          #stores word from price array into $v0 // might have to move outside loop

            add $t5, $0, $v0        #stores price into $t5

            li $v0, 4           #outputs please enter amount of coupon
            la $a0, str5
            syscall

            li $v0, 1           #prints counter
            add $a0, $t1, $0
            syscall

            li $v0, 4           #prints colon and tab
            la $a0, str9
            syscall

            li $v0, 5           #loads integer into $v0
            syscall

            add $t3, $v0, $0        #adds input to t3

            bgt $t3, $t0, error3        #if input is > 10, go to error

            bgt $t3, $t5, error3        #if input is > price number

            sw $t3, 0($s1)          #stores the integer into array1

            add $t3, $t3, $v0       #adds number to sum

       increment:   add $t1, $t1, 1         #adds 1 to counter
                    add $t2, $t2, 1         #adds 1 to loop counter
                    add $s0, $s0, 4         #increments array
                    add $s1, $s1, 4         #increments array 2

                    j read1

        end1:   add $v1, $t3, $0        #adds coupon sum to v2

                jr $ra                  #returns back to addresss




error1:     li $v0, 4           #outputs too many items to purchase
            la $a0, str1
            syscall

            j main  

error2:     li $v0, 4           #outputs too many coupons
            la $a0, str4
            syscall

            jr $ra

error3:     li $v0, 4           #outputs coupon is not acceptable
            la $a0, str6
            syscall

            sw $0, 0($s1)

            j increment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Failure

So, the problem lies in `FillCouponArray`. There is some extraneous code in it which could be streamlined, but that's not the main problem. Your code is failing to keep a proper cumulative sum.

Let's look at the last part:

```
li $v0, 5               #loads integer into $v0
syscall

add $t3, $v0, $0        #adds input to t3
bgt $t3, $t0, error3    #if input is > 10, go to error
bgt $t3, $t5, error3    #if input is > price number
sw $t3, 0($s1)          #stores the integer into array1
add $t3, $t3, $v0       #adds number to sum
```

After reading the coupon value in, you store it in `$v0`. Then, you store it in `$t3`. That looks fine, at first. The two error checks are fine and dandy too. Saving it to the array is also normal.

However, the last line is where it first breaks down. `add $t3, $t3, $v0` equates to `$t3 = $t3 + $v0`. So, for an input of `9`, if all checks pass, `$t3 = 9 + 9 = 18`. Not okay. Already your cumulative sum is double.

But this is a two-stage failure. When the loops comes back to the next input, it does `add $t3, $v0, $0` which is `$t3 = $v0 + 0`. You are now overwriting `$t3` with the new input, destroying the cumulative summation.

At the very end, what you will most likely see is your item total minus double your last coupon. Which you probably don't want.

#### The Solution

It's been 3 years since I've written MIPS, and since this is for an assignment, I would say the fastest way to make this work is to replace your cumulative sum tracker `$t3` in `add $t3, $t3, $v0` with another available register, and return that register.

If you'd like to clean this up more, I'd suggest a few of changes:

1. No need to move `$v0` to `$t3`. You can just use `$v0` to do your checks.
2. Don't really need an array if you are doing a simply cum sum with the input.

That's it. Hope it works.

Comment: In addition to this, the registers that are summed into should be clear prior to the respective loops. Otherwise you're likely to see incorrect results if you try to execute the program twice in a row.